# SequentialWriter generate csv in java

Tags: java, csv

I am generatiuon a csv using he sequentila writer. My problem is the below line

```
  CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
  DefaultSerializerProvider.Impl sp = new DefaultSerializerProvider.Impl();
  sp.setNullValueSerializer(new CustomNullSerializer());
  csvMapper.setSerializerProvider(sp);
  //csvMapper.enable(CsvGenerator.Feature.ALWAYS_QUOTE_STRINGS);
  //csvMapper.disable(CsvGenerator.Feature.ALWAYS_QUOTE_EMPTY_STRINGS);
  csvMapper.setDateFormat(dtFormat);


try { seqW.write(new Object[]{"\r"});} catch (IOException e) {throw new UncheckedIOException(e);}
```

I wan tot print a carriage return. The output always shows the this

---

```
Label,"Business Rule Id","Key List",Level
"20000  -  ccccc-xxxxxx(INC SUBS)",ROLLPO,20000
,"27367  -  ccccc-xxxxxx",ROLLPO,27367
"                                                   /// I don't want to see this.
"
"20715  -  ccccc-xxxxxx ENTITY",ROLLPO,20715
,"20723  -  ccccc-xxxxxx",ROLLPO,20723
,,"20769  -  ccccc-xxxxxx",ROLLPO,20769
,,,"20896  -  ccccc-xxxxxx-LE",ROLLPO,20896
,,,,"50012  -  ccccc-xxxxxx",ROLLPO,50012
```

I want to see this:

```
Label,"Business Rule Id","Key List",Level
"20000  -  ccccc-xxxxxx(INC SUBS)",ROLLPO,20000,
,"27367  -  ccccc-xxxxxx",ROLLPO,27367



"20715  -  ccccc-xxxxxx ENTITY",ROLLPO,20715,
,"20723  -  ccccc-xxxxxx",ROLLPO,20723,
,,"20769  -  ccccc-xxxxxx",ROLLPO,20769,
,,,"20896  -  ccccc-xxxxxx-LE",ROLLPO,20896,
,,,,"50012  -  ccccc-xxxxxx",ROLLPO,50012
```

Comment: *I wan tot print a carriage return.* Why? Carriage returns are (part of) record separators (which is why it is being quoted), so that behaviour is expected. What did you *think* you'd see?

Comment: How should I process in order to add space between records without invoking that behavior

Comment: A csv file *already has* a separator between records (a line separator) or it's not a csv file